# The effect of Special Relavity's Time Dilation on Rocket propulsion

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, rocket-science

I'm familiar with how the mass of an object increases with the velocity, which makes it impossible to reach the speed of light. However does time dilation also add challenges to accelerating an object?

Ignoring how you get the spacecraft up to relativistic speeds, would time dilation make a rocket engine less effective as it reduces the flow rate the rocket engine?

Comment: Incidentally the spacecraft's mass does _not_ increase, but see the reference in my answer for the full story . . .

Comment: what does effective mean here?

Comment: By effective I meant the rate that the engine is able to do work, or eject propellant

Answer (score 2):

There is a very old but fantastic article on *precisely* this subject - the [Relativistic Rocket](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html).  I don't think I can really add much to the Great Man's words, so just read and enjoy.

Comment: This is a link-only answer... But I have to agree, that is an excellent article, and I've linked to it countless times. ;)

Comment: Well, I haven't seen a better answer _anywhere_, so why should the OP settle for an inferior one when they can have this link?

Comment: Thank you for the fascinating link does explain lots of curious effects including the effective mass, energy requirements works with the vehicle changing mass. It also mentions the slight difference in time dilation at the front and rear of the rocket.

The formula makes the assumption of a constant acceleration/deceleration, what I'm curious to know is does time dilation have any influence on the ability of a rocket motor to produce the required level of acceleration (In terms of Wattage or Impulse per unit time)